# Writing fast codes in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a large dataset with two main columns including courier code
and their related delivery date & time

```
CourierTrips.head()
```

> ```
>   Courier Code    Delivery Date Time
> 0 1232011104      2019/04/15 18:38
> 1 1232011104      2019/04/15 12:00
> 2 1232011076      2019/04/15 14:00
> 3 1232011076      2019/04/15 12:10
> 4 1102095903      2019/04/15 18:01
> ```

I want to identify the last delivery time of each courier in each working day. 
First, I separated the date and time columns into different columns, using two different codes that one of the codes was very faster than the other code:

**First Method (Very Slow):**

```
#Delivery Date
CourierTrips["Delivery_Date"]=""
for i in range(len(CourierTrips["Delivery_Date"])):
    CourierTrips["Delivery_Date"][i]=CourierTrips['Delivery Date Time'][i][:10]

#Delivery Time
CourierTrips["Delivery_Time"]=""
for i in range(len(CourierTrips["Delivery_Time"])):
    CourierTrips["Delivery_Time"][i]=CourierTrips['Delivery Date Time'][i][11::]
```

**Second Method (Very Fast):**

```
#Delivery Date
CourierTrips["Delivery_Date"]=[u[:10] for u in CourierTrips['Delivery Date Time']]

#Delivery Time
CourierTrips["Delivery_Time"]=[u[11::] for u in CourierTrips['Delivery Date Time']]
```

Both of the above-mentioned codes have the same results for separating the date and time values, but the second method is very faster than the first method.

Then, for identifying the last delivery time of each courier in each working day, I must calculate the maximum value of the "Delivery Date Time" column in a day, for each specific courier code. Thus, I could write the below code to save the results in the End Time column.

```
CourierTrips["End_Time"]=""
for i in range(len(CourierTrips["End_Time"])):
    CourierTrips["End_Time"][i]=max(CourierTrips[(CourierTrips['Courier Code']==CourierTrips['Courier Code'][i]) & 
                     (CourierTrips["Delivery_Date"]==CourierTrips["Delivery_Date"][i])]['Delivery_Time'])

CourierTrips.head()
```

> ```
>   Courier Code    Delivery Date Time  Delivery_Date   Delivery_Time   End_Time
> 0 1232011104      2019/04/15 18:38    2019/04/15      18:38           21:10
> 1 1232011104      2019/04/15 12:00    2019/04/15      12:00           21:10
> 2 1232011076      2019/04/15 14:00    2019/04/15      14:00           21:05
> 3 1232011076      2019/04/15 12:10    2019/04/15      12:10           21:05
> 4 1102095903      2019/04/15 18:01    2019/04/15      18:01           19:45
> ```

The results of the above code is true, but unfortunately, the execution time of the code is too much. My data set contains more than 1 million records and the above code spends A LOT OF TIMES for the results. 
As I explained, I could write a fast code for adding the date and time columns, but unfortunately, I could not find a good solution to write a fast code for calculation of the values of the End_Time column. 
My question is that, is it possible to write a code that spends low time to show the results of the End_Time column? 
I would be grateful if anybody can help me by answering my question.

Comment: Split data in X (x=4 for example). X will be number of threads, do the same job en each worker with the splited data. So the jobs will be done 4 times at same time, with ammount data 250K instead 1M

Comment: @Wonka Bad solution. There is no need for looping over the `dataframe` rows.

Comment: +1 for "don't loop over the df". Use the built-in functionality of pandas as shown by @Aryerez. Btw. in the first looped version, you write to `CourierTrips["Delivery_Date"]` in each iteration. In the second version, using a list comprehension, you only access `CourierTrips["Delivery_Date"]` once, putting the whole list there. That's why it's most likely faster.

Answer (score 2):

Don't loop over `pandas dataframe` rows. As you already saw for yourself, it is never the answer. You can find the latest time for each `Courier Code` with:

```
last_times = CourierTrips[['Courier Code', 'Delivery_Time']].groupby('Courier Code').max().reset_index()
```

And then merge the results into `CourierTrips` with (instead of the entire last part of the code you wrote):

```
CourierTrips = CourierTrips.merge(last_times.rename({'Delivery_Time':'End_Time'}, axis=1), how='left')
```